# 'HttpClientHandler.set_AutomaticDecompression' not found Error using Azure Mobile Services in Xamarin forms from Azure Project

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I am creating a new App, using Xamarin forms.  The App uses Azure Mobile Services v2.0.1.

The app runs fine on IOS but when running on Android I get the following error.

```
 'HttpClientHandler.set_AutomaticDecompression' not found
```

Googling this, the answer seems to be to make sure Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries are installed for the PCL project and the Android App.

I have installed this in my Droid App but am still getting the error.  Any further ideas?

My Package.config - with the http client in is:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="modernhttpclient" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="SQLitePCL" version="3.8.7.2" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
```

Comment: Did you also install `Microsoft.Net.Http` in your PCL? What's defined in the `packages.config` of the PCL project?

Answer (score 1):

You are using ModernHttpClient, which requires additional setup (most notably adding a NativeMessageHandler() to the client invocation.

Needless to say, Azure Mobile Apps does not do this for you natively.

Try using

`var client = new MobileServiceClient(yourUrl, new NativeMessageHandler());`

... instead of the normal call.  Alternatively, try without ModernHttpClient.

Comment: I tried both suggestions. I defined like this this.client = new MobileServiceClient(
                URL, new ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler() { AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip |                                              System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate});

This didnt work. I removed the reference for ModernHttpClient but still crashing. what else can be done I dont know.

Comment: You can't be having the same error if you removed ModernHttpClient.  What is the new error?

Comment: I tried to remove the reference without uninstalling the package because other package from xamarin is depending on this package but obviously this doesnt work. I dont understand how to continue from here without uninstalling ModernHttpClient